# How to handle multiple threads in a for each when using Data Table

Tags: c#

I have a function in javascript which repeatedely call this method for checking if the this data is exist o a new member of employee. But I am getting an error message which says

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

```
public class Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails
    {
        public string uamnumber;
    }

    static List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails> Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber_Details = new List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails> { };

    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]

    public List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails> Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber(string csp,string firstName,string middleName,string lastName,int mode)
    {
        DataTable table = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "[Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber]";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csp", csp);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleName", middleName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", mode);

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        table = this.dbConn.ExecuteDataTable(cmd);

        Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber_Details.Clear();

        lock (table)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails _list = new Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails();

                _list.uamnumber = row["UAM #"].ToString();


                Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber_Details.Add(_list);
            }
        }


        return Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber_Details;
    }
```

I found some answers but nothing seems to work. I am trying the `ToList()` but it does not seem available in a `DataTable` I also tried `lock` which don't work too. How can I handle this?

Comment: You may want to review duplicate I used for previous iteration of the question and check maybe your code have list that modified from multiple requests... something like `static List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails> Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber_Details`. It is unclear what exactly you don't understand from that explanation...

Comment: Use a local `List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails>` that you create, populate and return inside the function.  I'm assuming `Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber_Details` is a global var that you create elsewhere.  This may or may not resolve the issue (can't tell from just the above code), but you shouldn't be using global vars (unless really necessary) in an API (again, an assumption from the info we have).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for that. Now I understand that i should just only use a local variable on this scenario. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Archer Thank you for that. Now I understand that i should just only use a local variable on this scenario. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails> Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber_Details` is redundant. Use function local variable without `lock`

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails> Checker_DuplicateUAMNumber(string csp,string firstName,string middleName,string lastName,int mode)
{
    /* 
    ADO.NET preparation and executions removed for brevity 
    */

    var result = new List<Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails>;

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        result.Add(
            new Checker_DuplicateUAMNumberDetails
            { 
                uamnumber = row["UAM #"].ToString()
            }
        );
    }

    return result;
}
```